# Create POSTGRES User With Airflow Python

Tags: postgresql, airflow

I'm trying to create a user in a POSTGRES using Airflow.  In Airflow, the statement executes successfully. However, when using the password to connect to the database (unhashed) I get the following error:

```
connection to server at "<host>" (<ip>), port <port> failed: 
FATAL: password authentication failed for user "my_user"
```

Questions:

1. Do I have to md5 hash the password?
2. Are there any characters the password cannot contain?

Here is my airflow code

```py
import hashlib
import secrets
import string

from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.postgres.operators.postgres import PostgresOperator

# create password
length = 32
characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
password = "".join(secrets.choice(characters) for _ in range(length))
password = password.replace("'", '"')

# hash password
password_hash = hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()

with DAG(dag_id="my_dag") as dag:
    create_user = PostgresOperator(
        task_id="create_user",
        postgres_conn_id="<MY CONN ID>",
        sql=f"CREATE USER my_user WITH PASSWORD '{password_hash}';",
    )
```

Comment: 1) Postgres version 2) This `hashlib.md5(password.encode()).hexdigest()` is probably not doing what you think it is. If you have a user with sufficient privileges  you could look at  the system  catalog `pg_authid`, where I'm pretty sure you will see something different. Also in the connect string the password needs to be plain text.